# Safety way to remove functionality from Android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have 2 versions of application - Free and Pro (flavors). Now I added some additional functionality to Pro version. What is the safety and proper way to make it functionality not available for Free version? For example, if I just remove some buttons on "Free" layout - is it enouth, or I must to override all java code to make it not included in Free version? Is it possible what if someone "hack" Free app and return on it layout from Pro version?
Search was not geaving me result.
Thanks.

**UPD:** To be clear, this question is not about product flavors and gradle system - i know basic information about it. This question about that is it possible to hack the application by simply replacing in compiled apk some variables, such as boolean variable or string (and make it "Pro"). For example replace in some places "false" on "true" and get Pro version with full functionality. I dont know anything about it, but some reason i think its possible (because it`s java, I think). Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have the two flavours a separate modules on Android Studio.

In your case, for example you have an Activity(with its layout) MyActivity.java has a pro and a free version. Pro version has tree buttons while free has only two.

So, you can either have the MyActivity.java contained inside the main module, but you'll have two files for the layout, one inside the pro module (this layout will contain three buttons) and another inside the free module (this, on the other hand will contain only two buttons).

Inside MyActivity.java code you can distinguish wether you're using free or pro flavour and make all the conditions.

Another option is to have two MyActivity.java clases (one on each flavour module) with the corresponding implementation.

Comment: Yes, it`s that exactly what i`am doing now - differents layout for each flavor. It`s more easy and do not duplicate java code (like 2 Activities). But i`am scare if someone return my buttons in free version layout. Is it possible? I don`t know enything about hacking android applications. Now I start to think that is this questions for thouse hacking app (for hackers), but not for stackoverflow :-) Sorry if i wasting someone's time...

Comment: @kolombo you shouldn't worry about that, please see [build system concepts](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts) "The source code of the product flavor is used in addition to the source code of the main configuration" If you change flavours using AS you'll see that the not-selected flavour is completely ignored. Although, you'll need to use proguard if you're concerned about reverse engineering being applied to your app.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now I will separate functionality with easiest way for me and do not worry about it. Most likely I just have paranoia).Thanks for the link, I will read it. It`s save my time.

Comment: +! for proguard. Not only does it obfuscate (making it harder for hackers to hack... and for you to read stacks), but it also minifies, strips out code that is not used. If your free flavour (and main, obviously) doesn't call on the pro code at all, then proguard can strip it out.

Answer (score 2):

Two options :

1. If you are having a server component, you can have a registration feature and let the server tells the app whether the user is allowed to use the Pro version or not.
2. The recommended way is to go for In App Purchase. Goole has provided api s for the same and you can check the details with the help of Google In App Purchase SDK. Based on that you can enable the pro feature.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about inAppPurchase for most safaty way. But now its late to implement it, because I already have 2 applictions in market and if I was implement it before, it will be remove Ads from app and provide additional functions. But now I think its late :( I have`t external server for checking registration, now I`am using only default android checking licencing for Pro version. InAppPurchase, apparently, the best way for it. Sorry for english

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to implement a class with constants or static methods which differs the functionality of your free or pro version in each flavor source set.

Maybe a BuildConfig field is enough. You can generate it in your gradle file:

```
 productFlavors {
    pro {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PRO", "true"
    }
```

and access it via

```
BuildConfig.PRO
```

Another way is to access the flavor as:

```
BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("pro")
```

Comment: Oh. I didn`t know that (access to flavors). And, if i just check in "additional" functions like if(BuildConfig.PRO) {return;} - it will be enouth for make app "unhackable" for hackers? I mean, is it possible to extract apk and replace or delete this checking?

Comment: Of course there a ways to maniupilate the behavior of the app. Someone has to decompile it, change the specific code and compile it again. But the count of users which got these posibilities might be very low. The saftiest way is to authenticate user via a backenend

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Android Studio for developing? You can than configure the grade build file to build two different flavors of your application. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) for a detailed description how to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, i use Android Studio and flavors, but now i think about to make app unhackable and at the same time make deleloping more easy and faster, than i need to separate functionality beetween 2 versions of applications.